# Updating existing element in XML with PHP

Tags: php, xml

Currently, im having this for appending data to my items file:

```
    $xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
    $xmldoc->load('ex.xml');


    $item= $xmldoc->createElement('item');

    $item->setAttribute('id', '100');
    $item->setAttribute('category', 'Fitness');
    $item->setAttribute('name', 'Basketball');
    $item->setAttribute('url', 'http://google.com');
    $item->setAttribute('description', 'This is a description');
    $item->setAttribute('price', '899');


    $xmldoc->getElementsByTagName('items')->item(0)->appendChild($item);
    $xmldoc->save('ex.xml');
```

Now before appending this, I would like to check for an existing element "item" that has the same attribute id value.

And if it does it should update that element with these new data.

Currently it just appends and doesnt check anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmldoc->load('ex.xml');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($xmldoc);
$query = $xpath->query('/mainXML/items/item[@id = "100"]');

$create_new_node = false;
if($query->length == 0)
{
    $item = $xmldoc->createElement('item');
    $create_new_node = true;
}
else
{
    $item = $query->item(0);
}

$item->setAttribute('id', '100');
$item->setAttribute('category', 'Fitness');
$item->setAttribute('name', 'Basketball');
$item->setAttribute('url', 'http://google.com');
$item->setAttribute('description', 'This is a description');
$item->setAttribute('price', '899');

if($create_new_node)
{
    $xmldoc->getElementsByTagName('items')->item(0)->appendChild($item);
}
$xmldoc->save('ex.xml');
```

Comment: Doesnt work, tried this and the query solution you just had - it just appends still

Comment: And it should be $xmldoc->getelementbyid, not $doc, but i fixed that still nothing

Comment: Still nothing, it just appends

Comment: @Karem:  It works for me, so you'd better post your XML file.

Comment: @Karem:  Fixed.  I suggest you look into XPath, as it will help you a lot when dealing with XML.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used this functionality but looks like a good match for [DOMDocument: Get Element By ID](http://php.net/manual/en/function.domdocument-get-element-by-id.php)

If you get a matching element, edit it, and if not, post away.

Comment: `getElementById` will not work with xml unless it has a DTD which specifies which attributes are `ID` type

Answer (score 0):

If you have a DTD for this xml file that specifies that the "id" attribute is an `ID` type (i.e. its value is unique in a document and uniquely identifies its element), then you can use [`DOMDocument::getElementById()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.domdocument-get-element-by-id.php).

Most likely, however, you do not have a DTD. In this case, you should just use XPath:

```
$xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmldoc->load('ex.xml');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($xmldoc);
$results = $xpath->query('//items/item[@id=100][0]');

if (!$results->length) {
    $item= $xmldoc->createElement('item');
    $item->setAttribute('id', '100');
    $item->setAttribute('category', 'Fitness');
    $item->setAttribute('name', 'Basketball');
    $item->setAttribute('url', 'http://google.com');
    $item->setAttribute('description', 'This is a description');
    $item->setAttribute('price', '899');

    $xmldoc->getElementsByTagName('items')->item(0)->appendChild($item);
    $xmldoc->save('ex.xml');
}
```

You should also consider using [`SimpleXML`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) for this task. The way this xml is structured and manipulated would probably be better-suited to SimpleXML.